# DataBinding Fails but none of the usual causes

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

The databindings inside my rectangle objects are failing.  I suspect the datacontext isn't being passed along.  Here is the high level trace for DarkSquareColor:

```
 System.Windows.Data Warning: 56 : Created BindingExpression (hash=15409413) for Binding

(hash=9290279)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 58 :   Path: 'DarkSquareColor'

System.Windows.Data Warning: 60 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Default mode resolved to

OneWay

System.Windows.Data Warning: 61 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Default update trigger

resolved to PropertyChanged

System.Windows.Data Warning: 62 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Attach to 

System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush.Color (hash=62178992)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 64 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Use Framework mentor <null>

System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Resolving source 

System.Windows.Data Warning: 69 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Framework mentor not found

System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Resolve source deferred

System.Windows.Data Warning: 95 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Got  

InheritanceContextChanged event from SolidColorBrush (hash=62178992)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Resolving source 

System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Found data context element:

Rectangle (hash=59316889) (OK)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): DataContext is null

'Chess Piece Viewer.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):  

Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-
SystemXmlLinq\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXmlLinq.dll'

Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework-

SystemXml\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemXml.dll'
System.Windows.Data Warning: 67 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Resolving source 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 70 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): Found data context element: 
Rectangle (hash=59316889) (OK)

System.Windows.Data Warning: 71 : BindingExpression (hash=15409413): DataContext is null

Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\PresentationFramework- 

SystemData\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\PresentationFramework-SystemData.dll'
```

Part of the Failing xaml:

```
    <Border BorderBrush="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.BoardBorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{Binding         Path=ChessBoard.BoardBorderThickness}" >
        <UniformGrid Rows="8" Columns="8" >
        <Canvas>
                <Rectangle x:Name="a1" Stroke="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Path=ChessBoard.DarkSquareColor, diagnostics:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High}"/>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
                <ContentControl DataContext="{Binding Path=ChessSquareViewModels[0]}"/>
            </Canvas>
 </UniformGrid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

ViewModel:

```
    namespace Chess_Piece_Viewer.ViewModels
{
class ChessGameViewModel :BaseViewModel
{
    #region BackingFields
    private IChessBoard _ChessBoard;
    private IChessGame _ChessGame;
    private DataTemplateSelector _ChessDataTemplateSelector;

    #endregion

    #region PublicFields
    public ChessSquareViewModel[] ChessSquareViewModels = new ChessSquareViewModel[64]; 

    #endregion
    #region Properties
    public DataTemplateSelector ChessDataTemplateSelector
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChessDataTemplateSelector;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ChessDataTemplateSelector != value)
            {
                _ChessDataTemplateSelector = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ChessDataTemplateSelector);
            }
        }
    }
    public IChessBoard ChessBoard
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChessBoard;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ChessBoard != value)
            {
                _ChessBoard = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ChessBoard);
            }
        }
    }
    public IChessGame ChessGame
    {
        get
        {
            return _ChessGame;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_ChessGame != value)
            {
                _ChessGame = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => ChessGame);
            }
        }
    }
    public ChessPieces[] CurrentPosition { get; set; }
    public int MoveIndex { get; set; }
    #endregion
    #region CTOR
    public ChessGameViewModel()
    {
    }
    public ChessGameViewModel(IChessGame chessgame,  ChessPieceDataTemplateSelector chesspiecedatatemplateselector)
    {
        this.ChessGame = chessgame;

        this.ChessDataTemplateSelector = chesspiecedatatemplateselector;
        this.ChessBoard = new ChessBoard();

        //initialize chesssquareviewmodels?
        for (int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
        {
            ChessSquareViewModels[i] = new ChessSquareViewModel();
        }
        MoveIndex = 0;
        //initialize moves?
        Positions = ChessGame.ChessPositionsasArray;
        CurrentPosition=Positions[MoveIndex];
         UpdateVisualChessSet();
        UpdateVisualChessPosition();
     } 
    #endregion

   }
}
```

Model:

```
 namespace Chess_Piece_Viewer.Models
{
class ChessBoard:IChessBoard
{
    private Color _DarkSquareColor;
    public System.Windows.Media.Color DarkSquareColor {
        get{
            return _DarkSquareColor;
        }

        set {
            _DarkSquareColor = value;
        }
    }
    public System.Windows.Media.Color LightSquareColor { get; set; }

    public System.Windows.Media.Brush DarkSquareBrush { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Brush LightSquareBrush { get; set; }
    public System.Windows.Media.Brush BoardBorderBrush { get; set; }
    public double BoardBorderThickness { get; set; }
    #region CTOR
    public ChessBoard()
    {
        DarkSquareColor = Colors.Black;
        LightSquareColor=Colors.White;

        DarkSquareBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        LightSquareBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
        BoardBorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        BoardBorderThickness = 2;

    } 
    #endregion
}
}
```

Poor Mans Dependency Injection:

```
    public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);
        MainWindow = new Chess_Piece_Viewer.MainWindow();
       // IChessSet chessset = (IChessSet) MainWindow.FindResource("Chaturanga Chess Set");
        ChessPieceDataTemplateSelector dts = new ChessPieceDataTemplateSelector();
        var examplechessgame = new Chess_Piece_Viewer.Models.DesignTimeData.ExampleChessGame();

        var MainViewModel= new Chess_Piece_Viewer.ViewModels.ChessGameViewModel(examplechessgame, dts);


        //var MainViewModel = new Chess_Piece_Viewer.ViewModels.MainWindowViewModel();
        //MainViewModel.BoardViewModel = new ViewModels.ChessBoardViewModel();
        MainWindow.DataContext = MainViewModel;
        MainWindow.Show();

  }
 }
```

Comment: In one property you bind to `ChessBoard.DarkSquareBorder` then you bind to only `DarkSquareColor`?

Comment: sorry that was just me trying to troubleshoot the databinding problem using a shorter path.  A shorter path did not work.  I'll edit the code :)

Comment: maybe try to init the chess board in the getter .

Comment: I tried initialized the chess board in the getter instead of the constructor but the results were the same :(

Answer (score 0):

I wasted 2 days being a dunce :)  The problem was the classic I was using a similar but wrong view model.  Nothing special to learn from this question :(

Comment: You can delete the question, as it is useless for other visitors in its current state.